# has_many through blowing away the association's metadata on mass association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

Hey,
Not a Rails noob but this has stumped me.
With has many through associations in Rails.  When I mass assign wines to a winebar through a winelist association (or through) table with something like this.

```
class WineBarController

  def update

    @winebar = WineBar.find(params[:id])

    @winebar.wines = Wine.find(params[:wine_bar][:wine_ids].split(","))  // Mass assign wines.

    render (@winebar.update_attributes(params[:wine_bar]) ? :update_success : :update_failure) 

  end

end
```

This will delete every winelist row associated with that winebar. Then it finds all of the wines in wine_ids, which we presume is a comma separated string of wine ids.  Then it inserts back into the winelist a new association.  This would be expensive, but fine if the destroyed association rows didn't have metadata such as the individual wine bar's price per glass and bottle.

Is there a way to have it not blow everything away, just do an enumerable comparison of the arrays and insert delete whatever changes.  I feel like that's something rails does and I'm just missing something obvious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem looks like it's with your first statement in the update method - you're creating a new wine bar record, instead of loading an existing record and updating it.  That's why when you examine the record, there's nothing showing of the relationship.  Rails *is* smart enough not to drop/create every record on the list, so don't worry about that.

If you're using the standard rails setup for your forms:

```
<% form_for @wine_bar do |f| %>
```

Then you can call your update like this:

```
class WineBarController
  def update
    @winebar = WineBar.find(params[:id])
    render (@winebar.update_attributes(params[:wine_bar]) ? :update_success : :update_failure) 
  end
end
```

You don't need to explicitly update your record with `params[:wine_bar][:wine_ids]`, because when you updated it with `params[:wine_bar]`, the wine_ids were included as part of that.  I hope this helps!

**UPDATE:** You mentioned that this doesn't work because of how the forms are setup, but you can fix it easily.  In your form, you'll want to rename the input field from `wine_bar[wine_ids]` to `wine_bar[wine_ids_string]`.  Then you just need to create the accessors in your model, like so:

```
class WineBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  def wine_ids_string
    wines.map(&:id).join(',')
  end

  def wine_ids_string= id_string
    self.wine_ids = id_string.split(/,/)
  end
end
```

The first method above is the "getter" - it takes the list of associated wine ids and converts them to a string that the form can use.  The next method is the "setter", and it accepts a comma-delimited string of ids, and breaks it up into the array that `wine_ids=` accepts.

You might also be interested in my article [Dynamic Form Elements in Rails](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/07/dynamic-form-elements-in-ruby-on-rails/), which outlines how rails form inputs aren't limited to the attributes in the database record.  Any pair of accessor methods can be used.

Comment: thank you for your reply but that doesn't work.  the wine_ids field is not a nested form.  it's a string.  my UI doesn't fit well with the nested form convention.  i updated my example to be an update. duh.  but an extra step is still needed to query for the wine ids and then associate them with the wine bar.